# Is Guava Striped.get(key) synchronized?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, guava

I'm concerned if the Guava Striped.get(key) method synchronized.

So is this class thread safe?

```
class UrlLocker  {
    Striped<Lock> locks = Striped.lazyWeakLock(1);

    public void lock(Url url) {
        locks.get(url).lock();
    }

    public void unlock(Url url) {
        locks.get(url).unlock();
    }
}
```

Or do I need to synchronize my method to protect accessing the locks map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diving into guava MapMaker implementation, I see that the magic is in the method com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.ComputingSegment#getOrCompu‌​te which protect the critical section where the Lock is computed and put in the Map.

Answer (score 1):

To make it completely thread safe you would need to declare `locks` instance as `final`:

```
class UrlLocker  {
    final Striped<Lock> locks = Striped.lazyWeakLock(1);

    public void lock(Url url) {
        locks.get(url).lock();
    }

    public void unlock(Url url) {
        locks.get(url).unlock();
    }
}
```

Also, correctness of your code depends on `#hashcode` implementation of `Url` class itself. If you would use `java.net.URL` (it doesn't look like you do) hashcode would change if you'd loose [internet connection](http://michaelscharf.blogspot.com/2006/11/javaneturlequals-and-hashcode-make.html) of if DNS resolution would change between calls.

Extract from `Striped` javadoc:

> ...assuming {@link Object#hashCode()} is correctly implemented for the
>   keys...

Comment: could you explain why making locks "final" ensures that accessing locks is thread safer?

Comment: @GuillaumeDelafosse: Assignment to a final field has a _happens-before_ relationship with access to that field from another thread. This is not the case for assignment to a non-final, non-volatile field. I think that at least in theory, a thread calling a method on your `UrlLocker` immediately after it's created (on a different thread) could see the `locks` field uninitialized. Regardless, you should always make fields final if they don't need to change.

Comment: Got it.
Anyway, are you sure locks.get is safe. I mean, is there a chance two thread calling it  won't make the Striped create two instances of Lock for the same key?
I tried to dive into Guava implementation but I didn't find any synchronization while getting and creating the Lock in the cache...

Comment: @GuillaumeDelafosse it not necessarily need to be synchronized in order to be thread safe. Implementation which you'll get from is `LazyStriped` (it;s private static class in guava) and for getting lock it will use guava's `MapMaker` which is thread safe and designed to be used in concurrent environment.